# Nginx Rewrite Dynamic URls with .php extension

Tags: php, nginx, url-rewriting

I am trying to rewrite domain.com/reviews/(dynamic).php to /reviews/index.php?slug=$1

Here is my server block which doesnt work. Keeps giving me a 404 when i try a dynamic url to rewrite.

```
location / {
    index index.php index.html index.htm;
    try_files $uri $uri/ =404;
}

location ~ \.php$ {
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}

location /reviews/ {
    rewrite ^/reviews/(.*).php$ /reviews/index.php?slug=$1 last;
}

error_page 404 /404.php;
```

When I remove the .php from the rewrite line and try `/reviews/namehere`, it works just fine.

Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The URLs that end with `.php` are all processed by the `location ~ \.php$` block, so the location containing your `rewrite...last` statement is not found. Which explains why it works when you remove the `.php`.

The destination URL `/reviews/index.php?slug=$1` also matches the conditions for the `rewrite`, so any solution needs to be especially careful to avoid a redirection loop.

Try moving the rewrite statement into the `location ~ \.php$` block, and changing it to `rewrite...break` statement to avoid a potential redirection loop.

For example:

```
location ~ \.php$ {
    rewrite ^/reviews/index.php$ /reviews/index.php break;
    rewrite ^/reviews/(.*).php$ /reviews/index.php?slug=$1 break;
    include snippets/fastcgi-php.conf;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php/php8.1-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

Also, add another `rewrite...break` statement above it (as shown), which prevents a request to `/reviews/index.php` from becoming corrupted.

Comment: Hi Richard, if you have some time can you help on this one:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78070870/nginx-redirects-for-file-downloads