# nginx redirects for file downloads

Tags: nginx, nginx-location

I have a location block in nginx for my appservers that handles requests from clients who want to download binary objects ending in .bin that are stored on a CDN server.

```
 location ~ ^/file/blob/dl/(.+\.bin)$ {
    set $filename $1;
    return http://<some_cdn_url>.com/$filename;
 }
```

However when I make a request to my server that is for /file/blob/dl/xyz.bin it returns a 302 but doesnt actually fetch the file, how can I fix this?

I tried to do a rewrite as well instead of the return, it does something similar and returns a 301 without actually fetching the file. I can download the file directly from the cdn URL without issues.

```
 location ~ ^/file/blob/dl/(.+\.bin)$ {
   set $filename $1;
   rewrite ^(.*)$ http://<some_cdn_url>.com/$filename permanent;
 }
```

What other options can I do to solve this?

Comment: How do you download the file directly? Using a browser? Can you download the file using `curl`? Maybe the CDN operates some anti-hotlinking strategy.

Comment: I use curl and it works. In fact if I hardcode a location for the file it works via nginx too. But if I use a regex then it doesnt work. I tried a proxy_pass to the CDN URL with the filename tacked to the end but it gives a 502. Comparing with the case where it works I think the issue is that my upstream_addr is set to blank, I have no idea how or why that happens :-(